# Plotting trajectory with latitude longitude

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I am interested to plot time series data of moving object using latitude and longitude data...I have looked and haven't found anything before I give up I thought I would ask here...Is there a package?

I am looking at [something like this](http://biostat.jhsph.edu/~jleek/code/simplystats.png):

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you could explain how does that work: how is supposed the data to be given to TeX, or anything that may ease the way to an answer.

Comment: Thank you for your input!! I would like for to input the latitude and longitude and then create an arc connecting them as nodes...does that make sense?

Comment: If you detail a little more in the question, I think it would be better, write an example of how it's exactly expected to behave, putting an example list of latitudes and longitudes (and how would you input them, as a table may be?) and an image of what you would expect.

Comment: Is there a package?  Not that I know of.  Can it be done?  Absolutely.  First you need a world map (e.g. Mercator) and the transformation from latitude and longitude to x,y coordinates.

Comment: Perhaps you could use [`pst-geo`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-geo). I don't really know much about it though, so I cannot say for sure if it is helpful.